# csipsimple on windows

Tags: android, windows, pjsip

I want to run csipsimple using eclipse on Windows OS. I downloaded the project with SVN, and copied the 2 `libpjsipjni.so` files to `CSipSimple\libs\armeabi` and `CSipSimple\libs\armeabi-v7a`.

Now, I recieve 272 errors and from going over them i see that they are on things like:

```
import org.pjsip.pjsua.pj_pool_t;

private pj_pool_t dialtonePool;
```

Does someone accomplished to bypass those errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK found the answer!
apparently there were missing files of pjsua jni on the org folder.
in order to get them [download them from here](http://nightlies.csipsimple.com/dev_helpers/org.tar.gz)
extract them into org folder and all your problems will fly away.